# Testing stripe.redirectToCheckout using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, stripe-payments

The problem that I am experiencing is that when I click the checkout button on Stripe domain page (the selenium is losing the session ). I am using JWT tokens, so the question is how should I access localStorage to get the token and later on to pass it to the browser ( I am not sure that this will actually work, so if there is some other way please give me a hand ). I got this code before the execution of the test:

```
const { Before, After } = require('cucumber');
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
const config = require('../config');

let driver;

Before(async () => {
  driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox');
  if (config.headlessBrowser === 'true') {
    const screen = {
      width: 1920,
      height: 1200,
    };
    driver = driver
      .setFirefoxOptions(new firefox.Options().headless().windowSize(screen));
  }
  driver = driver
    .build();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  exports.driver = driver;
});

After(() => {
  driver.quit();
});
```

And the tests for clicking the submit button and expected URL when redirected:

```
Then('I press stripe checkout button', {timeout: waitTime}, async () => {
    await d.driver.findElement(By.className('SubmitButton')).click();
})

Then(/I should be redirected to "(.*)"/, {timeout: waitTime}, async (path) => {
    await d.driver.wait(until.urlIs(config.url + path), waitTime);
});
```

I can see that it is trying to redirect me to the correct success URL, but unfortunately, it logs me out( I assume that is happening because the session is lost ).

Comment: I don't know enough about Selenium to understand if this is something specific to Stripe or generally related to how selenium works. However, it's broadly recommended to not to automated tests against Stripe like this, instead treating those parts as a black box and testing before and after (ie, skip to the success or failure landing page, maybe trigger some webhooks).

Comment: There is a user @Salami who managed the e2e testing of stripe.redirectToCheckout, unfortunately, I have only 49 reputation and I cannot leave him a comment.